# android create textViews in tableRows programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-event

I have these three lists with the same number of elements

```
List<String>competitoinsIDs = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String>marks = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String>numOfQuestions = new LinkedList<String>();
```

I want to put the first element of each list in a tablerow , then the second element of each list in another tablerow, would you help me please, this is the xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlMarksTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksCompetitionID"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Competition"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksMarks"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Marks"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksQuestionsNum"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Questions"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First change your XML file to:

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlMarksTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

We'll add all the content dynamically.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    List<String>competitoinsIDs = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String>marks = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String>numOfQuestions = new LinkedList<String>();

 //make sure that the lists contain data or else display will be blank screen

    TableRow.LayoutParams  params1=new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params2=new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlMarksTable);
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<marks.size();ctr++)
    {
    //Creating new tablerows and textviews
    TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
    TextView txt1=new TextView(this);
    TextView txt2=new TextView(this);
    TextView txt3=new TextView(this);
    //setting the text
    txt1.setText(competitoinsIDs.get(ctr));
    txt2.setText(marks.get(ctr));
    txt3.setText(numOfQuestions.get(ctr));
    txt1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    txt2.setLayoutParams(params1);
    txt3.setLayoutParams(params1);
    //the textviews have to be added to the row created
    row.addView(txt1);
    row.addView(txt2);
    row.addView(txt3);
    row.setLayoutParams(params2);
    tbl.addView(row);
    }

}
```

Comment: make sure that the lists contain data or else display will be empty. Check the answer. I have edited and added the layout params in the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

please see the android code here and use it in your activities `onCreate` method

```
setContentView(R.layout.table_layout_xml); // use your layout xml file here

TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlMarksTable);

List<String>competitoinsIDs = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String>marks = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String>numOfQuestions = new LinkedList<String>();


// adding static values to test the layout. use your dynamic data here
competitoinsIDs.add("123");
competitoinsIDs.add("124");
competitoinsIDs.add("125");

marks.add("56");
marks.add("57");
marks.add("58");

numOfQuestions.add("10");
numOfQuestions.add("11");
numOfQuestions.add("12");

TableRow tableRows[] = new TableRow[competitoinsIDs.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {

    tableRows[i] = new TableRow(this);
    tableRows[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tableRows[i].setWeightSum(2.0f);
    tableRows[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    text.setText(competitoinsIDs.get(i));
    tableRows[i].addView(text);

    text = new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    text.setText(marks.get(i));
    tableRows[i].addView(text);

    text = new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    text.setText(numOfQuestions.get(i));
    tableRows[i].addView(text);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRows[i]);

}
```

Comment: @tottiroma may i know what was the error ? i tried the very same code in my test project before posting the answer and it was working fine. so could you please post the logcat logs during the error. (just to clear the error. i know you got the answer and your problem solved)