# how to customize the header in table view_android, (picture is shown)

Tags: android, tableview

I am using a table View in my xml. Currently all the rows look the same(shown as the first table), so I want the header to be different to the following rows, such as the 1st table in the picture[image] 
I tried to set the first row as buttons but they look weird, does anyone got a idea? thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

this post [Android TableLayout Header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698978/android-tablelayout-header-row) may be helpful to you

they are using Tables inside tables

OR

see my answer in this post. [android create textViews in tableRows programmitcally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342975/android-create-textviews-in-tablerows-programmitcally/11343618#11343618)

- this question author is using fixed textviews as header in xml. here you can control the textview attributes to look them like headers
- then he is trying to add the table contents via program